# Is there a way to return an IAsyncEnumerable without using await foreach

Tags: c#

In the situation where MethodB's return signature is IAsyncEnumerable, and it is called from within MethodA, is it possible to return an IAsyncEnumerable, without iterating over the return value of MethodB as follows:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<T> MethodB() => do stuff;

IAsyncEnumerable<T> MethodA() => return MethodB(); <- this gives a compiler error: must use yield return;
```

According to the error message, I assume the only way to do this is as follows:

```
async IAsyncEnumerable<T> MethodA() => await foreach(var t in MethodB())yield return t;
```

Answer (score 6):

You're just using the wrong syntax for `MethodA` - you're using an expression-bodied member *and* a return statement. You can use a block-bodied member:

```cs
IAsyncEnumerable<T> MethodB() => null;

IAsyncEnumerable<T> MethodA()
{
    return MethodB();
}
```

or just remove the `return` statement:

```
IAsyncEnumerable<T> MethodB() => null;

IAsyncEnumerable<T> MethodA() => MethodB();
```

This isn't really specific to `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` - it's just that the return type has given you a slightly more confusing error message than you'd normally get:

```cs
// Invalid expression term 'return'
int Method() => return 0;
```

Comment: After trying the expression syntax in my code, it turns out that using a block bodied member with an async modifier generates the same compiler error, whereas the expression bodied member does not. Is there some reason these two are treated differently?

Comment: @cubesnyc: That's somewhat surprising, but I don't see why you'd want the `async` modifier there anyway, at least for this simple case. It looks like the compiler assumes that any `async` method with an async enumerable return type is an iterator - I *suspect* that's a bug, but I'm not sure. Note that if you declare the return type as `Task<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>` then it's fine. If you have a concrete example of why you *want* to use `async` on a method in this situation, I could give more details. Maybe ask it in a separate question though.